# Java Script + JSON Parsing and converting into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm looking for help in converting a particular elements in JSON message to an array using java script at run time. We wanted the script to be more generic. Actually we were trying the following which worked for single element and while changing it to handle for multiple elements at run time its not working.

```
//Working for Single element - Static 

var bodyContext = JSON.parse(response.content)
if(bodyContext.companylist.company.constructor !== Array){
    bodyContext.companylist.company = [bodyContext.companylist.company]
}
```

The above code works and converts Company in JSON message as a Array, Where as the below we tried for multiple elements is not working

```
//Not Working for multiple elements - dynamic

var bodyContext = JSON.parse(response.content)

var elementName = "";
//Loop runs every time and changes the value of elementName at every iteration

if(bodyContext.elementName .constructor !== Array){ //not working    

    bodyContext.elementName  = [bodyContext.elementName] //Not working
}
```

instead of looking for "`bodyContext.companylist.company`" and converting into Array, "`bodyContext.elementName`" is checked and added to the `bodycontext` object.

how to handle this. `ElementName` variable along with JavaScript object is not recognized. 
Please help.

Comment: Try a more concise title that describes the type of problem you're having, and leave the big explanation for the body of your post.

Answer (score 0):

you can JSON.parse(data) then you can fetch data from Javascript object like
$.each(Obj,function(key,value){

});

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use

```
bodyContext[elementName]
```

since

```
bodyContext.elementName
```

looks for a field in bodyContext named `elementName`, not the a field named after the *value* in `elementName`.

Also, you initialize `elementName` with `""`, and this won't match anything on the first iteration.